# How to delete fields from a partitioned table in Hive stored as parquet?

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet, impala

I'm looking for a way to modify a parquet data table in **HIVE** to remove some fields. The table is managed but it doesn't matter because I can convert it to external.
The problem is that I can not use the command `ALTER TABLE ... REPLACE COLUMN` with **partitioned parquet** tables.

It is works well for textfile format (partitioned or not) and only for non-partitioned parquet tables.

I've tried to replace column but this is the result:

```
hive> ALTER TABLE db_test.mytable REPLACE COLUMNS(name String);
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
Replacing columns cannot drop columns for table db_test.mytable. 
SerDe may be incompatible
```

I've thought about some solutions, but none of them fits my scenario:

**First**
- [Optional] Convert the table in external.
- Delete the table.
- Re-create the table with the fields that I want.
- MSCK REPAIR TABLE to add HDFS partitions.
- [Optional] Convert back to managed table.

**Second**
- Create temporary table as selection of the original table with the fields that I choose.
- Delete the original table.
- Rename the temporary table to the original name.

Both options affect my process because I would lose the statistics of my table. This table is consumed with MicroStrategy by Impala and I need to mantain the statistics.
In addition, the second solution is bad with very large data tables.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use first method and then run

```
hive> anayze table <db_name>.<table_name> compute statistics;
```

to compute all the [statistics](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatsDev) of the table.

Comment: I would like to keep the statistics. Recalculating statistics is CPU-intensive and can take a long time to complete for very large tables. This problem affects me due to the size of the tables and the number of partitions. I have to calculate the statistics incrementally. Thank you anyway.